# using a while loop with an input and submit button to echo out in php the number of times they enter

Tags: php, input, while-loop, submit

I figured out my PHP script using a while loop, now I want to incorporate an input and submit button to have a user pick a date of the month from 1-31 and when they input a date I will have PHP echo out `"hello"` that many times they entered.

I just cant figure out how to tie it in with an input and submit button so as not to make my code hard coded, I want to make it dynamic.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   Enter the date of the month: <input type = "text" name ="Enter the date of the month">
   <input type = "submit" name="submitDate">
</form>

<?php
    $x = 1;
    while($x<=31){
        echo "hello<br>";
        $x++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: first of all , Please write a good title that makes sense.your text input tag seems to be incorrect .please fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

your gonna need isset function of php to accept your html user input.
HTML

```
Enter the date of the month: <input type = "text" name ="date">
```

PHP

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submitDate'])) {
     $x = $_POST['date'];
    }
```

then you can use $x in your while loop to output hello.